# Как найти и заменить url на # в WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Необходимо заменить:

```
<p style="text-align:center"><a href="http://clprk.com/yQLy"><img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=b10993ad4594e7cf2&#038;n=13" style="width:75%"/></a></p>
```

на

```
<p style="text-align:center"><a href="#"><img src="#" style="width:75%"/></a></p>
```

Как это выполнить в wp если выводится следующим образом:

```
$yml .= '<description><![CDATA['.apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content()).']]></description>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Через `get_the_content()`

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно сработать, регулярное выражения заменит **ВСЕ** данные в `src` і `href` в контенте:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(href|src)\=\"(.*?)\"/ui', '$1="#"', apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content()));

$yml .= "<description><![CDATA[{$content}]]></description>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Здорово, работает, спасибо! А можно написать регулярное выражение именно на строку из примера или это не реально?

Comment: Так на него и написал, или что имеется виду, форматирования кода, чтобы было как в примере?

Comment: Да, там просто в коде ниже есть нужные ссылки. Можно регулярное выражение составить именно под `<p style="text-align:center"><a href="http://clprk.com/yQLy"><img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=b10993ad4594e7cf2&#038;n=13" style="width:75%"/></a></p>
`